# Cells inside UICollectionView do not render properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I'm new to iOS and Swift, I'm trying to create a `UICollectionView` for the first time.
Something is not quite right when running what I made. Here's what it looks like in my storyboard:

[image: Storyboard Cell]

But when I run:

[image: Simulator]

Top grey area became longer than before and bottoms of the cells seem clipped. I just wrote few lines of code to make the cells' height equal to the collection view's.

```
let height = collectionView.frame.height
cell.frame.size.height = height
return cell
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `collectionViewLayout` to give a size for an item,

```
class YourController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

and

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let height = collectionView.frame.height
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    return size
}
```

Comment: It works, everyone's answer so far is correct. But you are the firs. I gave your answer correct.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 code is here

1) Uncheck the **Automatic** field of the **Row Height** in the attribute inspector.

2) Then set the delegate funcitons

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var width = CGFloat(80)  //change "80" with your cell width

    return CGSize(width: width ,height : self.collectionView.frame.height)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change height in a collection view, do not change the cell frame height. There is another delegate for the collection view to set cell height and width.

```
extension ViewControll : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: anyWidth, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```

Here, `anyWidth` means whatever width you put. It's up to you

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes from storyboard or from code. I have done from storyboard as shown in image.

[image]

And also write this method in your view controller to give a size to your item. For that inherit `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method in your view controller.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

      let size = collectionView.frame.width / 3
      return CGSize(width: size - 20, height: size - 20 )
 }
```

**Note: This is just an example. You can set your collection view cell frame.**